# Gulp doesn't copy images

Tags: gulp

*here is my code:*

```
gulp.task('build-images-dev', function() {
  return gulp.src('./public/app/images/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist.dev/images'));
});
```

it should copy to `dist.dev/images` But it doesn't. I tried to understand where is the problem, could anyone help me plz?

*here is console:*

```
$ gulp build-images-dev
[16:40:07] Using gulpfile C:\projects\project\gulpfile.js
[16:40:07] Starting 'build-images-dev'...
[16:40:07] Finished 'build-images-dev' after 24 ms
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, so it's probably the path. Use [`gulp-debug`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to figure out if the files are found.

Answer (score 3):

```
  gulp.task('build-images-dev', function() {
    gulp.src(['imgs/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/imgs'));
  });

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('imgs/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}', ['build-images-dev']);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Agree with Nic.

Answer (score 1):

*issue closed:* The problem was that path was wrong. Anyway use `gulp-debug` for find a bug.